# Populating HTML select drop down with Javascript Copying Pointers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code where I want 25 identical "SectorList" Drop downs contained in an array SectorNames with 25 elements each accessed by their respective id's of the form "Sector1_1", "Sector1_2" .. etc. all the way to "Sector5_5" . 
 In the second snippet after filling one drop down I assign the other 24 drop downs to that one. Will this code work and will it have negative consequences for when I want to access each Sector Drop Down with their Id's later. It seems that this is a much simpler way then running the loop in the second snippet for each drop down since GlobalEntry[5] has thousands of entries.

```js
// first code snippet
var SectorNames = new Array(25);
var SectorString = "SectorList";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; j++) {
  for (var j = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    SectorString = SectorString + String(i) + "_" + String(j);
    SectorNames[i*5 + j] = document.getElementById(SectorString);
  }
}

//second code snippet
for (var i = 0; i < GlobalObject[5].length; i++) {
  var opt = GlobalObject[5][i];
  var el = document.createElement("option");
  el.textContent = opt;
  el.value = opt;
  SectorNames[0].options.add(el);
}

for (var j = 1; j < SectorNames.length; j++) {
  SectorNames[j] = SectorNames[0];
}
```

Comment: Your first loop is wrong. You're only setting `SectorNames[0]` through `SectorNames[4]`, not all 25 entries. Maybe you meant to assign to `SectorNames[i*j]`?

Comment: @Barmar edited thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning to `sectorNames[j]` doesn't change the DOM element, it just changes the Javascript variable. If you want to fill in the options of the `<select>` element, assign to its `innerHTML`.

```
var optionHTML = SectorNames[0].innerHTML;
for (var j = 1; j < SectorNames.length; j++) {
    SectorNames[j].innerHTML = optionHTML;
}
```